# Convergence in norm operator topology

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I have to prove that a sequence $A(\varepsilon)$ of operators between Hilbert spaces $A(\varepsilon):H_1\to H_2$ converges, when $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, to an operator $B:H_1\to H_2$ in the uniform norm of the space $B(H_1,H_2)$ (the space of bounded operators from $H_1\to H_2$).
So I have to prove that
$$\Vert A(\varepsilon)-B\Vert_{B(H_1,H_2)}\to 0,\,\,\,\varepsilon\to 0^+$$
where
$$\Vert A\Vert_{B(H_1,H_2)}:=\sup_{f\in D(A)}\frac{\Vert Af\Vert_{H_1}}{\Vert f\Vert_{H_2}}$$.
I've found that for every $f\in H_1$
$$\Vert A(\varepsilon)f-Bf\Vert_{H_1}\leq C(\varepsilon)\Vert f\Vert_{H_2}$$
with the quantity $C(\varepsilon)\to 0$ when $\varepsilon\to 0^+$.
Can I conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\Vert A(\varepsilon)f-Bf\Vert_{H_1}\leq C(\varepsilon)\Vert f\Vert_{H_2}$$
implies
$$\frac{\Vert A(\varepsilon)f-Bf\Vert_{H_1}}{\Vert f\Vert_{H_2}}\leq C(\varepsilon),$$
you have
$$\Vert A(\varepsilon) - B\Vert_{B(H_1,H_2)}:=\sup_{f\in D(A)}\frac{\Vert A(\varepsilon)f - Bf\Vert_{H_1}}{\Vert f\Vert_{H_2}} \le C(\varepsilon).$$

Comment: So I have the desired convergence!